# Deno - Gitlab Private Repo

Tags: git, import, module, gitlab, deno

Have created a multi-repo project. Aka each repo can execute seperately but also relies on other modules (which can also execute seperately) for specific tasks.

These are all stored in a private gitlab account/project/repo.

After doing some reading, it looks like GitLab don't support PA tokens for reading a private repo like Deno suggests.

Deplying manually with a Deploy Token works as expected aka

```
https://{username}:{token}@gitlab.com/{user}/{project}/{repo}.git
```

However, I'm looking to automate the deployment process as much as possible. So it'd be great to get any info required to make this possible. Is there an alternative method to achieving a simple import?

```
import { something } from 'https://gitlab.com/{user}/{project}/{repo}/mod.ts'
```

Is there something I'm missing? or is this only achievable manually/hooking into the GL API to automate it yourself/moving to a supported git solution (github)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic auth support was added [back in version 1.8](https://deno.com/blog/v1.8#auth-token-support-for-fetching-modules). All you need is set the environment variable, and Deno will use that against the correct domain when fetching the imports

```
DENO_AUTH_TOKENS=a1b2c3d4e5f6@deno.land
```

*However* at the time of writing this on June 10th 2021 (version 1.11.0 of Deno) it's still not possible to use it with GitLab. The reason actually has nothing to do with authentication; the URL to get the raw source returns `application/json` as the Content-Type, which Deno doesn't recognize as a valid import. This is an issue that has to be resolved on GitLab's side, there is [already an issue opened](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/325466) to track the progress.